# How to set acr-values for Sustainsys external provider in identity server 3

Tags: saml-2.0, identityserver3, kentor-authservices, sustainsys-saml2

I have `Idsvr3` with local user accounts in SQL. In addition i have also configured  external identity provider which support SAML2 using https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2 I followed the [sample here](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/tree/master/Samples/SampleIdentityServer3)

Now when user access the client application he gets redirected to login page which presents userid/password textboxes for local login and also a button to redirect to external provider.

I want to change this behavior. I want user directly goto external login based on some condition. I've [read that](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/authorization.html) I can pass the required login provider to the `acr_values` and IdSvr3 will directly go to external provider.

Here is how i registered external provider with `IdSvr3` *(Note some code is removed for brevity)*

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
        {
            var identityServerOptions = new IdentityServerOptions
            {
                AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions()
                {                        
                }
                .Configure(ConfigureIdentityProviders),                    
            };

            idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(identityServerOptions);
        });            
    }

    private void ConfigureIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
    {                           
            // SAML2
            var options = new Saml2AuthenticationOptions(false)
            {
                SPOptions = new SPOptions
                {
                    EntityId = new EntityId("https://localhost:44300/IdSrv3/Saml2"),
                },
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
                Caption = "SAML2p"
            };

            UseIdSrv3LogoutOnFederatedLogout(app, options);

            options.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase + "/App_Data/Sustainsys.Saml2.Tests.pfx"));

            options.IdentityProviders.Add(new IdentityProvider(
                new EntityId("https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/Metadata"),
                options.SPOptions)
            {
                LoadMetadata = true
            });

            app.UseSaml2Authentication(options);            
    }
}
```

and here is client application startup

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {            
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(CK);

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "https://localhost:44300/identity",
                Scope = "openid profile email",
                ClientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost:36102/",
                ResponseType = "id_token",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",               

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {                    
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (n) =>
                    {
                        if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.AuthenticationRequest)
                        {
                           if(SomeCondition == true)
                           {
                              n.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = "idp:saml2";
                           }
                        }

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }                
            });
        }        
    }
```

However identity server throws error `External login error: provider requested saml2 is not a configured external provider`

What is the valid name for `Sustainsys/Saml2` provider and where is it configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i found it. The `idp` is actually the value of `AuthenticationType` property.
During external provider setup in IdentityServer3, the `Saml2AuthenticationOptions` by default sets the AutheticationType to `Saml2`. 
So in client application i have to use exact same value as `acr-values`, it is case-sensitive. I was using small `s` instead of capital `S`. When i changed to `Saml2` it worked.

I can also override AutheticationType to any string i want, and that is good because now i can setup multiple external IdP that supports SAML2 protocol and differentiate them by their AutheticationType

Also i found this documentation helpful
https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/saml2/latest/saml2.pdf

Take a look how okta is configured with `IdentityServer3` in section `2.5.4 Step 3: Configure your identity server with the new identity provider`

Also from IdentityServer [documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/identityProviders.html)

> AuthenticationType must be a unique value to identify the external
>   identity provider. This value will also be used for the idp claim in
>   the resulting tokens. Furthermore the same value can be used to
>   pre-select identity providers during authorization/authentication
>   requests using the acr_values parameter (see this for more
>   information). This value is also used to restrict the allowed identity
>   providers on the Client configuration.